# How to efficiently write on a file C

Tags: c, performance, io

I'm playing with C and I'm astonished by the speed of IO operations.

And since I know nothing about C I was wondering if there is also a more efficient way to do the same thing.

Here my code, **how would you improve it?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
        int i;
        clock_t begin = clock();
        FILE * fptr;
        fptr = fopen("test.dat", "w"); 
        for (i = 0; i<10000000; i++) {
            fputs(" struingsjdhfju djshf dhsf s", fptr);
        }
        clock_t end = clock();

        double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        printf("Time elpased is %f seconds", time_spent);
        fclose(fptr);
        sleep(10);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: « astonished by the speed » How? Do you find this example too slow? And if so, compared to what?

Comment: fputs() uses buffered i/o so you probably need a fflush() before you time it to make sure it's actually written out.  You could try open/write in 4k blocks/close.

Comment: No, I find it incredibly fast

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with writing with `fputs()` or `fputc()`, etc.. The underlying I/O operations will use a buffer to store and write data to the file in an efficient manner, buffering data until a `'\n'` is encountered or the buffer is full. There are no other sneaky/faster ways to do direct file I/O. You may eek a bit more performance by using `mmap()`, but there isn't going to be an orders of magnitude in improvement.

Answer (score 2):

The C language is a compiled language (like C++, Rust, Go etc), and without garbage collector, as opposed to interpreted language (like JavaScript, Python etc).

As such it enjoys a performance that can still be developed further:

- By vectorization (SSE, MAVX). Basically it like if you are cutting bananas with a knife, and then you decide to take 3 bananas at a time: you will be able to slice them just as fine)
- By multithreading: You are not awaiting for an operation to finish to start computing another, it also increases the performance with the caveat that your function must have a runtime high enough to be worth it since it consumes time to initialize each thread. To take back the example with the bananas it is like if you gather some friends to cut the bananas together, each at his own pace.
- By reducing branching (trim off if else and use binary operators instead, although it may hurt readability): branching seriously impact performance, as each time there is a miss it can be very costly.
- Speaking of conditions, and this point is valid in any language, it is always best to check the condition that is most likely to happen first like `if (a&&b)` : if a is more often false than b, it should be set first. This is often overlooked, even by experienced programmers, who will (also rightly) choose to focus on null-safety.
- in your case, you could achieve easily a much higher speed by copying your string to a buffer of size, let's say, 65536 (if not bigger) and writing everything at once. Even for C, I/O operations are not cheap. You maximize greatly speed with a sizeable buffer and fewer fputs.
- Last, but not least, you can have the compiler optimizing the bytecode compiled by using the optimization flag, like `gcc -O3 main.c`

---

If you want to read more about how much you can tune your functions you should read optimization manuals from Agner Fog.

Also, welcome into the C world! You will not regret all the magic and freedom C can provide! What was your alma mater language if I may ask?